# multi-model form, placing new form at top of list using build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So Im [following the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#building-a-multi-model-form), and I created a nested record form, huzzah, but I was wondering how to get the new form to appear at the TOP of the list instead of the bottom. Right now when every time I submit my form, the new blank form for the nested model is placed at the bottom of the list. How can I get it to appear at the top?

edit the code is basically the same as:

```
<% @post.tags.build %>
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
  field 1
  field 2
  field 3
...
  <%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
       ...
       ...
    <%end %>
<%end %>
```

which produced

```
 Post Field 1
   Post Field 2
   Post Field 3

    TAGS
      previously created record 1
      previously created record 2
      previously created record 3
      ...
      Blank form!
```

But I want my nested for to look like:

```
 Post Field 1
       Post Field 2
       Post Field 3

        TAGS
          Blank form!
          previously created record 1
          previously created record 2
          previously created record 3
          ...
```

Comment: new form to appear at the top as in the tag form to appear at top?

Comment: You really need to show more of the code for us to better understand the problem.

Comment: this code is almost exactly the same as the railsguide exanple [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#building-a-multi-model-form) except i have different model names

Answer (score 0):

It's an assumption but I believe it is because `@post.tags.build` will add a new record at the end of currently stored records. You could maybe do something like:

```
<% tags = [@post.tags.build] << @post.tags %>
[...]
<%= form.fields_for :tags, tags do |tag_form| %>
    [...]
```

This way `fields_for` uses the modified array in which we have placed the new tag at the front.

Note: I haven't tested this so I apologize for any mistakes. I have also removed pieces that don't need to be changed.